# I made database structure in Firestore like this: I have two collections: 1)students 2)schools. I can not get array from my database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in my `Firestore database`.

From first `collection('schools')`, I need to get current user school. I did it and it is Ok. But I also need to use this school and get array of his school's available courses.

This array is situated in `collection('students')`. And as document I use `schoolNameString` which I took in previous collection. So in `document(schoolNameString).data['available']`, available is array of swings and I need

```
setState(){
    myarrayvar = document(schoolNameString).data['available'] 
}
```

I can not do that and always see

```
error /flutter (25070): Tried calling: []("available")
```

This is my code:

```
class _Coirses_PageState extends State<Coirses_Page> with TickerProviderStateMixin
{
    final _firesore = Firestore.instance;
    String appBarName;
    String studentSchoolString = 'mal';
    String aseetRoadforCorcs;
    List availableCorsces = [];
    @override
    void initState() {
        FirebaseUser user;
        super.initState();
        getCurrentUser();
        getCouses();

        try {
          var studentSchool = _firesore.collection('schools');
          var docSchool = studentSchool.document(loggedInUser.uid);
          docSchool.get().then((documents) {
            setState(() {
              studentSchoolString = documents.data['schoolName'];
              print(studentSchoolString);
            });
            print(studentSchoolString);
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }

        tabs = [
          Tab(text: 'Barlyǵy',),
          Tab(text: 'Oqyp jatyrmyn',),
          Tab(text: 'Aıaqtadym',)
        ];
        pages = [Progress_Bar()];
        _controller = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);
    }

    Future<List<dynamic>> getCouses() async {
       var document = Firestore.instance.collection("students").document(studentSchoolString).    get();

       return await document.then((doc) {

           setState(() {
            availableCorsces = doc.data['available'];
           });
           print('dsasdasdjnasndklasndasdkasld' + doc.data['available']);
           return availableCorsces;
       });
    }

    void getCurrentUser() async {
        try {
           final user = await _auth.currentUser();
           if (user != null) {
            loggedInUser = user;
            print(loggedInUser.email);
          }
       } catch (e) {
          print(e);
       }
    }
}
```

I expected that I can use it in my UI like `Text: ('available[0]' ......)`
But I can't.

Comment: Can you please add the full error message? Is `error /flutter (25070): Tried calling:` the complete error message?

Comment: it is not like error, it couldn't just take data but I can share it:E/flutter (25070): Receiver: null
E/flutter (25070): Tried calling: []("available")
E/flutter (25070): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (25070): #1      _Coirses_PageState.getCouses.<anonymous closure>.

Comment: The error says that there is no key called `available` for `document(schoolNameString).data`. You might want to check the value of `document(schoolNameString).data`.

Comment: but I have it( I can show screen

Comment: Please add the value of that to your question.

Comment: I did, but in console it even doesn't print something, it seems like it can't get .document(schoolNameString)

Comment: What do you mean it can't print something? Is that statement not even getting called?

Comment: yes, it can't get document because I have print statement but in console I don't see print('dsasdasdjnasndklasndasdkasld' + doc.data['available']);

Comment: In that case it looks like `document.then` is failing. You might want to check in the `catchError` what the error is.